# Dynamic view using UIhint in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a view in MVC3 framework where the view will behave dynamically based on the data. I was taking an approach to create an Interface for the model and the view is displaying the model based on the class which implements the interface.
For example, suppose I have an Interface IData and it has only one property Data. Now I am creating two models Dog and Cow, which are derived from IData. I am using UIHint attribute to Dog and Cow class to use some display template to render Data in those classes.   I am taking this approach to use the same view class to render both models. The model data for the View is IData, not cow or dog. However I noticed that when I use @Html.DisplayFor(m=>Model.Data) it s not using appropriate template to  render the data. Later I realized that, the lambda expression is passing the model type as IData, not dog or cow and therefore, MVC framework is not able to find appropriate template. Is there any alternative to achieve the same goal?
Thanks,